# Libapr .so files don't have the functionality of source code

Tags: c, epoll, shared-libraries, apr

I compiled libAPR sources and ran successfully  all tests provided by Apache.

However when I link my program to libapr.so the same functionality is not present.

For instance, **apr_pollset_add** primitive doesn't work. It returns always 1 (when it should return 0) and doesn't work (in the source test works like a charm).

I modified all the code of APRlib related to that primitive so it would just return -1. When I run the Apache tests, they present expected behaviour (return -1), however once again when I call the primitive from .so libs it is always returning 1.

I am almost sure the lib has just a wrapper on that function wich returns always 1.

Any clue on what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure you are linking the exact same lib that you compiled?

Comment: Yes. Deleted the old ones. Tried to compile, and my program returned error because it didn't find them, Then did 'make install' and my program compiled successfully again. So I am pretty sure I am using the new libs.

Comment: of course before make install, I did make and make clean. ^^

Comment: My money would be on a bug in the modifications you have made to APR, or that you have neglected something in your program. Sadly, we cannot know.

Comment: Listen I didn't modify the function to add functionality. I modified the function, so that its unique line of code is 'return -1' to check if the behaviour is reproduced in the lib (which is not happening). I did modified because with APR unmodified that function doesn't work.

Comment: Please help me on this. For some reason the installed libraries are not preserving functionality that exists and runs in the apr source folde, namely with the tests (which are ok).

I was searching and tests are compiled pointing to a .la file.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I found the problem.

I had libapr already installed in my system, so whenever I would use -libapr-1, it would link my program to the previously installed version of libapr. That was the reason it was not responding to my code modifications.

Regarding **apr_pollset_add** primitve, it is working well. The error is returned by the system when apr calls **poll_ctl**, because I was adding a regular file descriptor which is not accepted.